# Bibliography heading on every page

Tags: biblatex, sectioning

My thesis guideline states that bibliographies should continue to next page with heading "Kaynaklar Dizini devam ediyor" (meaning "Bibliography Continued"). 
I'm using `memoir` and `biblatex`. How can I manage this?

My MWE is below

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{memoir}          
\usepackage{polyglossia}            
\setmainlanguage{turkish}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Language=Turkish]{Times New Roman} 
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Zotero.bib}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace ve\space}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers={\space vd \space}}
%---------------CHAPTER STYLE-------------
\makechapterstyle{bolum}{%
\renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\par\nobreak\vskip \baselineskip} 
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}   
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}{\chaptitlefont\MakeUppercase} 
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}         
\renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}           
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter . \space} 
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
\afterchaptertitle
}
%--------------------

%---Page Numbering----
\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\makeoddhead{chapter}% Tek sayılı sayfaların üstbilgisi
 {}% Tek sayfa üstbilgi Sol 
 {}% Tek sayfa üstbilgi orta
 {\thepage}% Tek sayfa üstbilgi sağ
\makeevenhead{chapter}% Çift sayılı sayfaların üstbilgisi
 {}% Tek sayfa üstbilgi sol
 {}% Tek sayfa üstbilgi orta
 {\thepage}% Tek sayfa üstbilgi sağ  
\makeoddfoot{chapter}% Tek sayılı sayfaların altbilgisi
 {}% Tek sayfa altbilgi sol
 {}% Tek sayfa altbilgi orta
 {}% Tek sayfa altbilgi sağ
\makeoddfoot{chapter}% Çift sayılı sayfaların altbilgisi
 {}% Tek sayfa altbilgi sol
 {}% Tek sayfa altbilgi orta
 {}% Tek sayfa altbilgi sağ

%----------------------------

\chapterstyle{bolum}
\pagestyle{chapter}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Deneme}
fnrejgnrğthnsv.njgıtnhğwrytnh.ngıtjhgosejg. \cite{spencer_brief_2008},       \cite{guo_microstructure_2014}, \cite{zhang_differential_2008},  \cite{kesim_augmented_2012}, \cite{popov_numerical_2010}, \cite{kim_interactive_2012}, \cite{keehan_influence_2006}, \cite{manova_evolution_2004}, \cite{carruthers_material_????},\cite{shevtsov_optimal_2005},\cite{m.j._neale_d19_1996}
\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered, title={KAYNAKLAR\space DİZİNİ}]
\end{document}
```

What I want to achieve is Bibliography as seen below
[image]
Second page
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/401135/35864 help? It is a question about the style you seem to have written, so the requirements should be similar.