# Biblatex second page title

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to format my thesis to university requirements. My university requires;
Second and Third Page of bibliography's title must be "KAYNAKLAR DİZİNİ (devam)"
I can't add title to bibliography's second or third page.

```
\printbibliography[ title={KAYNAKLAR\space DİZİNİ}] %numaralı olsun istersen 
optionlarda heading=bibnumbered, yaz
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: We need to know what documentclass you use. Please prepare a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). Do you need a new title or just the header? Can you show us a mock-up of what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using that template. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/esogu-thesis-template/rhtzptdyyhjk#.Vm7Bk_mLSVM

Comment: First page of bibliography already have title. (Added image) But i need to add title to other bibliography pages.

Comment: So you want the second page to have a title similar in style, but with a slightly different content? Please don't only link to the document class you use, provide a full MWE (click the link in my comment above to learn more) in your question.

Comment: Related (but never answered, so not really helpful, but for the link): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232534/35864

Comment: Related (with a real answer this time):https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47646/35864 I don't have time to look at this until tomorrow, but if someone else wants to have a go, that might be a good start.

Comment: The `\defbibheading{bibliography}` is useless since it appears after the bibliography, so it does not change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is inspired by [Re-displaying section headings after page-breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47646/35864)

We define a new bibheading that repeats the chapter heading on each following page with `\EveryShipout`. We need to clean up the code after the bibliography, this is what the redefinition of `\blx@endbibliography` does.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{memoir}          
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}


\usepackage{everyshi}
\makeatletter
\defbibheading{contbibnumbered}{%
  \chapter{#1}%
  \gdef\@cont@heading{%
    \if@twocolumn
        \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#1 (continued)}]%
      \else
        \@makechapterhead{#1 (continued)}%
      \fi
      \@afterheading
  }
  \EveryShipout{%
    \ifdim\pagetotal>\pagegoal
      \aftergroup\@cont@heading
    \fi%
  }%
}

\def\blx@endbibliography{%
  \csuse{blx@endenv@\blx@theenv}%
  \global\let\@EveryShipout@Hook\@empty%
  \blx@noitem
  \endgroup
  \blx@bibnote\blx@thepostnote
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Deneme}
\cite{worman,geer,sigfridsson,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}
\lipsum[1-10]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=contbibnumbered]
\chapter{Deneme}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```